# people can access the admin panel page with typing URL in address bar

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login page and a check page that never show. and a panel page for the user. The user inserts his username and password and then he enters in the panel page. I set a session for deny the people to access the panel page with typing URL in address bar, but it is not working.

```
<?php
$a="select * from users where username='".$_POST["user"]."' && password='".$_POST["pass"]."'";
$b=mysqli_query($conn,$a);
$c=mysqli_num_rows($b);
if(isset($_POST["btn"])) {
if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
{
    header("location:index.php?empty=1010");
    exit;
}

if ($c > 0)
{
    header("location:welcome.php");
    $_SESSION["x"]=1;
    exit;
}
else
{
    header("location:index.php?error=2020");
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

and the panel page is :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["x"]))
{
    header("location:index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
wellcome
```

where is my fault?
thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an access control feature, this is a hacker's dream. Anyone can do [anything they want to your server](http://sqlmap.org/) using this code because you take `$_POST` data and put it directly in your query creating a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

The first thing to fix is that. The good news is since you're using `mysqli` you just have to adapt your query to use **prepared statements** and use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add data safely. It's just an extra two lines of code and it makes all the difference.

The second thing to fix is you're storing passwords as plain-text. This is a **huge** problem. If your database gets leaked, which would be trivial considering the aforementioned SQL injection hole, everyone's personal data will be compromised. At the very least use proper [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing), such as the [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function in PHP.

The third thing is having a login page does absolutely nothing unless every other page that needs to be restricted verifies you're logged in. This is extremely easy to forget and a slip like this can mean administrative functions are open to any user who can guess the URL. This happened to WordPress once and it was disastrous.

I'd **strongly** advise you to abandon this code completely, forget you ever wrote it, and instead look at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/). There are a number out there that are highly secure and have all of this already implemented. For example [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)'s [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) is really quite good and offers a lot of benefits beyond being already tested and secure. It likely has features that would take weeks of your own time to do, even presuming you had the knowledge and time necessary to tackle them in the first place.

Frameworks make it almost too easy to add things like Google, Twitter, or Facebook sign-in because there are pre-written modules you can add. They also give you a solid foundation to build on and many examples of how to implement features and organize code, making your application a lot higher quality and way more maintainable both by yourself in the future and other people.